# Removing duplicates from a query with conditions in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of transactions with 880,095 records that I am querying.

There are duplicate Transaction ID's in the table that I would like hidden/removed when querying the table.

Eg 1.

- Transaction ID 001 is has two records
- The data in both rows is identical except for Interest Rate.
- Row 1 has interest rate of 5%
- Row 2 has interest rate has no rate and value in the cell is 0

I would like all duplicate Transaction ID's with no interest rate to be removed. This is simple enough, the complication is the following.

Eg 2.

- Transaction ID 002 has 4 records
- The data in all 4 rows is identical
- The interest rate in all rows is 0, ie there is no interest rate.
- I would like the query to return any 1 of these rows, and remove the other 3.

In summary, I need help designing an MS Access query where duplicate transaction Id's are removed where:

- Transaction ID has multiple rows, remove the row which  has a 0 Interest Rate value
- Transaction ID has multiple rows, with all Interest Rates values as 0. Remove all duplicates leaving just one row.

Please let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: If you don't want to simply select the non-duplicates, but actually remove (`DELETE`) them, please clarify.

Comment: I do have a view of deleting the duplicates in the future. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the "duplicate" rows differ **only** at the `InterestRate` and you never have more than one row with rate over 0, and (one more assumption) there is no negative interest rate, then you can simply:

```
SELECT 
    TransactionID, MAX(InterestRate) AS InterestRate,
    col1, col2, ..., colN               -- all the other columns

FROM
    tableX AS t
GROUP BY
    TransactionID,
    col1, col2, ..., colN ;             -- all the other columns
```